# Can one simplify the Codensity monad on Maybe?

Tags: haskell, monads, dependent-type, continuations, category-theory

The **codensity monad on a type constructor `f`** is defined by:

```
 newtype C f a = C { unC ∷ forall r. (a → f r) → f r }
```

It is well known that `C f` is a monad for any type constructor `f` (not necessarily covariant). The codensity monad is useful in several ways but it is a complicated type that contains a higher-order function under a universal type quantifier.

My question is, for what `f` can one show that `C f` is equivalent to a simpler monad that is defined without type quantifiers?

Some examples where a simplification is possible:

- `f a = a` (the identity functor), for which `C f a = a`.
- `f a = r -> a` (the Reader monad), for which `C f` is the State monad (`C f a = r -> (a, r)`).
- `f a = (w, a)` (the Writer monad), for which `C f a = ((a -> w) -> a, (a -> w) -> w)`
- `f a = a -> s` (a contravariant functor) and then `C f a = (a -> s) -> s` (the continuation monad).
- `f a = a -> a` (neither covariant nor contravariant) and the `C f a = List a`

In the first four of those cases, the type equivalence can be derived from the Yoneda identity: `forall r. (a -> r) -> F r = F a` when `F` is a covariant functor. The last case is derived via the Church encoding of the inductive type `List`.

I looked at some other examples and found that in most cases `C f` does not seem to be equivalent to anything simpler.

Even if we just take `f a = Maybe a` the resulting type does not seem to be equivalent to a simpler type expression:

```
 newtype CMaybe a = CMaybe { unCMaybe ∷ forall r. (a → Maybe r) → Maybe r }
```

The Yoneda identity cannot be used here. My best guess (I have no proof so far) is that `CMaybe a = (a -> Bool) -> Bool` with some additional laws imposed on the functions of that type. Imposing equations on values can be adequately expressed only within a dependently-typed language.

Can one simplify the codensity monad on `Maybe`?

Are there other examples of type constructors `f` where `C f` can be simplified to a type without type quantifiers?

Comment: My guess is that `CMaybe` is a bit more complicated. A value for `CMaybe Int` could take `f` as input, compute `map f [0..99]`, and observe which results are `Nothing` or `Just x_i`. Depending on these "100 bits" of information, we can either return `Nothing` or `Just x_j` which is more or less like returning a number in `[-1..99]` (`Nothing` or the index `j`). So... maybe it's closer to `(a -> Bool) -> Nat`? I can't really say.

Comment: I think the problem is that `Maybe` is a sum type `Maybe a = 1 + a`, and sum types are defined by mapping out. Instead here you have a mapping *into* a sum. You essentially have `(1+r)^(1+r)^a` which, even as a high-school algebraic expression, doesn't have a compact form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a function `C Maybe a` returns a bit more information than a boolean because the `r` it returns identifies a single input in the callback, so **`f k` chooses an `x` such that `k x` is `Just`.**

Simplifying the callback type from `a -> Maybe r` to `a -> Bool`, we obtain the following dependent function type, written in Agda and in Coq respectively for reference:

```
-- Agda

(∀ {r} → (a → Maybe r) → Maybe r)
≡
((k : a → Bool) → Maybe (∃[ x ] k x ≡ true))
```

```
(* Coq *)

(forall r, (a -> option r) -> option r)
=
(forall (k : a -> bool), option { x : a | k x = true })
```

Proof of equivalence in Agda: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/79846cce777f0394a6f69d84576a325b

This proves the equivalence of `∀ {r} → (a → Maybe r) → Maybe r` and  a type without a quantifier: `((f : a → Bool) → Maybe (∃[ x ] f x ≡ true))`, which is equivalent to `q:: (a → Bool) → Maybe a` with the restriction that `q(p)` equals `Just x` only if `p(x) = true`.

---

Note that if `a` is finite, then `C Maybe a` is also finite. One approach to the problem then is to compute the corresponding cardinality function.

- You can reinterpret the expression of the cardinality as a type, giving a solution to your problem for types of the form `Finite a -> C f a`.
- You can look it up on the online encyclopedia of integer sequences, to find alternative combinatorial interpretations. Sadly, [the relevant sequence](https://oeis.org/A064320) doesn't have much information.

  ```
  Product_{j=1..n} j^C(n-1,j-1)

  -- https://oeis.org/A064320
  ```
- If you could find a simpler type for `C f a`, with only sums, products (not indexed by the cardinality of `a`), and exponentials, this may correspond to a non-trivial combinatorial identity. Conversely, difficulty in finding such a combinatorial identity provides compelling evidence for the non-existence of simple solutions. It also gives a quick way to test a candidate simplification for validity, by comparing its cardinality with the expected one.

Comment: Could you write more explicitly here the types that you have proved to be equivalent?

Comment: Could you prove formally that `forall r. (a -> Maybe r) -> Maybe r` is equivalent to `(a -> Bool) -> Maybe a` with additional restrictions?

Comment: I gave a link to an Agda proof.